# Bootstrap dropdown not aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem aligning dropdown menu. It is not aligned properly and it is flowing depending on the resolution. Have no idea what causes this.

[image: FullHD]

[image: Tablet view]

```css
.nav .dropdown {
        margin-top: -0.5rem;
    }

    .btn {
        padding: 2px 10px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
    }
    
    img {
        height: 2.5rem;
        filter: greyscale(100%);
    }
    
    img:first-child {
        padding-right: 1px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu {
        min-width: 1rem
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <img src="img/united-kingdom.svg" alt="UK version">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/united-states.svg" alt="usa version"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position relative to main div, and position absolute to individual drop-down elements

```
.nav
 .dropdown{
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
    position: relative;   // for keeping it alligned on same line
 }
.btn{
  padding: 2px 10px
  background-color: transparent
  border: none
}
img{
  height: 2.5rem
  filter: grayscale(100%)  
}
img:first-child{
  padding-right: 1px  
}
.dropdown-menu{
  min-width: 1rem 
  position: absoulute // for keeping it aligned on same line
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It sort of worked. I noticed there is a .open class and I needed to adjust its width